# Magento indexing product not showing on Google

Tags: magento, indexing

I have a strange problem, I think, with magento product and indexing on Google. I have uploaded my sitemap on search console and I have 311 on 418 pages indexed. This is normal as I discovered searching online. But, if I use the command [site:] on my domain I see only 12 pages also with Google excluded similar result, so if for each result page there are 10 pages, it see only 120 pages, most of them general pages and some products. This can be also normal, as I read online because the right indexing result is the one from search console. But, if I search some product name followed by the domain name, so for example, " table domaniname" it show only product from other competitors. Only if I search one of the products seen with the[site:] command followed by my domain name Google show it in the first result. So I don't understand, why if there are indexed 311 pages, I can't search them directly. I tried with others my sites and all result are showed right if combined with the domain name. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: it is google related... not magento directly...

Comment: Is there a programming-related question here?

Comment: I think you can be more out off topic than me with your answers. bye